# regex - get two string from this string: [(10.3.4.5/001_3CX)]

Tags: c#, string, extract

I have a string: `[(10.3.4.5:83/001_3CX/asd_43)]`

From this string I want to get two strings:

> 10.3.4.5:83

> 001_3CX/asd_43

What is the best solution for this?
I'm coding in c#.

Comment: _edited by Wiktor Stribiżew_ now you know it's RegEx time :D

Comment: @fubo  I'm Waiting for Enlightenment :)

Comment: Regex is a good choice for this. If you find it difficult to formulate the correct regex pattern for your use case, there are not only plenty of regex introductions/tutorials out there, but also online regex services that allow you to experiment with regex patterns. One such service that is specifically geared towards the .NET regex flavour is http://regexstorm.net/tester. Oh, and it is always never a bad idea to keep the [.NET regex language quick reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) open in a browser tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx appraoch https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ZJhUL

```
string input = "[(10.3.4.5:83/001_3CX/asd_43)]";
Match result = Regex.Match(input, @"\[\((.*?)\/(.*)\)\]");
string first = result.Groups[1].Value; //10.3.4.5:83
string second = result.Groups[2].Value; //001_3CX/asd_43
```

Comment: Tnx, It works :)

Comment: nice, you're welcome - don't forget to care about exception handling

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = "[(10.3.4.5:83/001_3CX/asd_43)]";
test.replace_string_by_character("[(","");
test.replace_string_by_character(")]","");
// (current result) test = "10.3.4.5:83/001_3CX/asd_43"
int index = locate_character_inside_string("/",test);

string first_to_return = substring_basedon_index(test,0,index - 1);
string second_to_return = substring_basedon_index(test,index + 1, length(test));
// (result) first_to_return = "10.3.4.5:83";
// (result) second_to_return = "001_3CX/asd_43";
```

There are plenty of internet posts on the exact names of the functions and methods I've mentioned :-)